# "ERROR: syntax error at end of input" when running Do command

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, plpgsql, generate-series

I was trying to create a calendar table. The query below. I get the error in the title. Can someone explain why?

```
create table if not exists test_calendar (test_date date primary key);

do $$
declare
    i intEGER := 0 ;--, date datetime := '20090101';
Begin
    while i <= 10 loop
        begin
            insert into test_calendar (test_date) values (dateadd(dd,i,'20090101'));
            i := i + 1;
        end;
    end Loop;
$$ ;

SELECT * FROM test_calendar
```

Comment: What error you are getting, also explain what you want to do in `(dateadd(dd,i,'20090101'))` . also add `end` after `end loop`.

Comment: ERROR: syntax error at end of input.

Comment: trying to create a calendar table with 10 dates starting from 2009-01-01/

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 0):

The immediate cause of the error message is the missing `END` at the end.

```sql
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   i int := 0;
   _date date := '2009-01-01';
BEGIN
   WHILE i <= 10 LOOP
      BEGIN  -- expensive noise
         INSERT INTO test_calendar (test_date)
         VALUES (_date + i);
         i := i + 1;
      END;
   END LOOP;
END  -- !
$do$;
```

A semicolon after the final `END` is optional.

But there is more:

- There is no `dateadd()` function in Postgres (like [in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24669753/939860)). You can simply add `integer` to a `date` for your purpose.
- The expensive [nested block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html) serves no purpose. Remove it.
- Such a loop is simpler and cheaper with `FOR`. See:

  - [Postgres FOR LOOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145761/postgres-for-loop/19147320#19147320)

```sql
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _date date := '2009-01-01';
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1..10  -- i defined implicitely
   LOOP
      INSERT INTO test_calendar (test_date)
      VALUES (_date + i);
   END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

#### Proper way

All of the above is just proof of concept. What I really would do:

```sql
INSERT INTO test_calendar (test_date)
SELECT generate_series(timestamp '2009-01-01'
                     , timestamp '2009-01-11'
                     , interval '1 day');
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f42962facee8c6fd3da0d5d52a5fd4ed)*

A set-based solution is generally better for this. Use `generate_series()` in Postgres. Detailed explanation:

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)

A single multi-row `INSERT` is much cheaper than many single-row `INSERT` commands.

The generated `timestamp` values are cast to `date` in the assignment. In other contexts you may need to cast explicitly.

Typically, you don't even need a persisted calendar table at all in Postgres. Just use `generate_series()` directly. Might be even faster.